# How can I say "You should save your work 'at short regular interval'?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say that "You should save your file *frequently at regular interval*" because this area has electricity problem.

I want **frequently at regular interval** in a word.

Comment: I would think that *frequently* is enough, by itself.

Comment: Also, if you end up using it, it's "...at regular interval __s__" (the plural of interval).

Comment: "Set the automatic-save interval to a small number."

Comment: "Save early and save often."

Comment: Both *frequently* and *regularly* should normally imply the other in OP's context, but if he thinks his audience are particularly literal-minded, he can just stick with his original - or perhaps more naturally, *"You should save your file regularly and frequently"*. The word *"interval[s]"* is unnecessary.

Answer (score 11):

*Frequently* will work by itself here, unless you mean that the intervals are to be of an exact duration. If this is the case you would say: "You need to save every 5 minutes", for example. The word *frequently* then becomes redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *[periodically](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/periodic)* to mean *fairly often and regularly*.

Comment: Hmmm. Periodically doesn't imply frequently to me. It doesn't seem any more frequent than regularly.

Comment: Periodic is less about the frequency and more about the regularity of the intervals. For example, women get their periods once a month.

Answer (score 3):

I think *regularly* works fine; the *frequent* part can be deduced by the context:

> ***This area has frequent electricity problems; you should save your files regularly.***

Answer (score 0):

*Frequently* actually means at frequent intervals.

*Repeatedly* means again and again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not understandable why one should save the file "at regular interval(s)" to prevent electricity problems effects, if this problems are (generally) random. If so, "at regular interval(s)" is both unnecessary and conceptually wrong; "frequently" is strictly enough. However, it is correct to add ", almost every hour" giving, implicitly, the minimal frequency. So, conclusively, I would say: "You should save your file frequently, almost every hour."